# type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, int>'

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

i am trying to save a map to shared preferences and load it back, i encode the map while saving and decoding it while loading, however i can't set the value of decoded json back to my original map which i saved, what is the data returned from my json decode?

```
 Map<String, int> purchasedItems =  {Sweet Pepper: 0, Lemon: 0, Eggplants: 0, Colorful Pepper: 0, Kiwi: 0, Fava Bean: 0, GrapeLeaf dolma: 0, Potatoes: 0, Spicy Pepper: 0, Grapefruit: 0, Tomatoes: 0, Cherries: 0, Red raddish: 0, Carrots: 0, Dolma: 0};
 Map<String, int> savedPurchasedItems = {};

void savePurchasesPrefs(Map<String, int> purchasedItems) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var something = jsonEncode(purchasedItems);
    var savePurchases = prefs.setString("savedPurchasedItems", something);
    print("saved purchases prefs $savePurchases");
  }

  void loadPurchasesPrefs() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var something = await prefs.get("savedPurchasedItems");
    print("loaded items: $something");
    var yee = jsonDecode(something);
    purchasedItems = yee;
    print("yee : $yee");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by changing the type of purchasedItems to Map everywhere and it worked prefectly fine.